# How to align two div's horizontally, with container width in percent?

Tags: css, html

Question:

I have the below HTML and want to have two divs horizontally next to each other.
The left div should have the same height as the right div (or vice-versa if the left div's height is greater than the right div's height).
The left div's size should be a fixed size in pixel, and the right div should expand to fill the container (no width to set), in this case 500px.

I don't want to set a width on the second div, because ultimately, I want to set the wrapper's size as percent.

With the HTML below, the second div goes below the first div.
Can anybody tell me how to fix this according to my wishes (should work in IE 9, too) ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>


    <style type="text/css" media="all">


        #wrapper 
        { 
            width: 500px; /* or say, 25% */
            border: 1px solid black; 
            overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */ 
        }

        #first 
        { 
            width: 100px; 
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid red; 
        }

        #second 
        { 
            border: 1px solid green; 
            width: 400px; /* don't want this */
            float: left;
        } 


    </style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
        Test left
        <br />
        Test left
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        Test right
        <br />
        Test right
        <br />
        Test right
        Auf der Registerkarte 'Einfügen' enthalten die Kataloge Elemente, die mit dem generellen Layout des Dokuments koordiniert werden sollten. Mithilfe dieser Kataloge können Sie Tabellen, Kopfzeilen, Fußzeilen, Listen, Deckblätter und sonstige Dokumentbausteine einfügen. Wenn Sie Bilder, Tabellen oder Diagramme erstellen, werden diese auch mit dem aktuellen Dokumentlayout koordiniert. Die Formatierung von markiertem Text im Dokumenttext kann auf einfache Weise geändert werden, indem Sie im Schnellformatvorlagen-Katalog auf der Registerkarte 'Start' ein Layout für den markierten Text auswählen. Text können Sie auch direkt mithilfe der anderen Steuerelemente auf der Registerkarte 'Start' formatieren. Die meisten Steuerelemente ermöglichen die Auswahl zwischen dem Layout des aktuellen Designs oder der direkten Angabe eines Formats. Wählen Sie neue Designelemente auf der Registerkarte 'Seitenlayout' aus, um das generelle Layout des Dokument s zu ändern. Verwenden Sie den Befehl zum Ändern des aktuellen Schnellformatvorlagen-Satzes, um die im Schnellformatvorlagen-Katalog verfügbaren Formatvorlagen zu ändern. Die Design- und die Schnellformatvorlagen-Kataloge stellen beide Befehle zum Zurücksetzen bereit, damit Sie immer die Möglichkeit haben, das ursprüngliche Layout des Dokument s in der aktuellen Vorlage wiederherzustellen. Auf der Registerkarte 'Einfügen' enthalten die Kataloge Elemente, die mit dem generellen Layout des Dokuments koordiniert werden sollten.
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can an exact height be specified on the `#wrapper`?

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff: Nope, height is unknown at compile & server-runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using border then your width has additional 2px.So Add 4px to wrapper width

```
#wrapper 
{ 
    width: 504px; /* or say, 25% */
    border: 1px solid black; 
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */ 
}

#first 
{   
    width: 100px; 
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}

#second 
{  
    border: 1px solid green; 
    width: 400px; /* don't want this */
    float: left;
}
```

Update :-Use table layout for this simple thing

```
 #wrapper 
        { display:table-row;
            width: 500px; /* or say, 25% */
            border: 1px solid black; 
            overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */ 
        }

        #first 
        { display:table-cell;
            width: 100px; 
            border: 1px solid red; 
        }

        #second 
        { display:table-cell;
            border: 1px solid green; 
         }
```

Comment: Nice, works - thank you ! However, use display: block instead of display:table-row in the wrapper, else it expands the wrapper.

Comment: no add a parent div to your #wrapper and then add display:table; to that and play with its width

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to you css:

```
div{
  margin:0;
  border:0;
}
```

And remove any borders previously specified... else reduce the width of the div you want on right

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bwuzm/

The border was adding additional 2px width

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to take a look at [css flexible box model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

I don't know if all browsers support this yet, but if you want the #wrapper to be flexible, #first to have fixed size, then #second to consume all the remaining space depending on the #wrapper width, maybe this would do the trick.

or try Somebody is in trouble's answer, using table is a quick solution for this if it's alright with you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The borders are making the `<div>`s just too big (by `2px`), so either remove the borders ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdMca/2/)) or create a negative `margin` ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdMca/1/)).

Comment: I'm working on a solution so I don't have to have `width: 400px; /* don't want this */`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ditch older browsers,try [CSS Tables](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/tables-the-next-evolution-in-css-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
#wrapper 
        { 
            width: 504px; /* or say, 25% */
            border: 1px solid black; 
            overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */ 
        }
```

Because borders around #first and #second blocks adds an additional 1px on each side of blocks. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghu7j/)

Or delete style with border add you will see everything will fall into places. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghu7j/1/)

And add display: inline-block to #first and #second blocks. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghu7j/)

Comment: But what about `width: 400px; /* don't want this */` on the `#second`? Remember that they `don't want this`.

Comment: If not the exact value of one of the blocks then just as table-cell.